# jQuery - event.delegateTarget vs $.proxy()

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy, event-handling

In my current project i find myself using a number of callback functions that are tied to various events and as such i am struggling to maintain the context of `this` as it relates to my constructor function. A typical example is this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(event) {
    // Do somthing..    
});
```

Currently i am using $.proxy() to maintain context. i.e

```
$('#foo').on('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
    // Do somthing..    
}, this));
```

I am reading the book "Instant jQuery Boilerplate for Plugins" where the author solves the same problem using `.delegateTarget` as such:

```
$('#foo').on('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
    var _this = $(event.delegateTarget).data("plugin_" + pluginName);
    // Do somthing..    
}, this));
```

So my question is this, is there any difference between using `event.delegateTarget` with jQuery's `.data()` and using jQuery's `$.proxy()` method?

Comment: You may be overcomplicating this. Why not just store a reference to the required `this` scope in a variable in the outer function which will be available for use within the inner function?

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i could certainly do that, i am simply trying discover if there is any advantage in using `.delegateTarget` or `$.proxy()`. What is the best practice ?

Comment: @andreas, i am not using ECMA2015 for this project.